# Capturing dollar and cents formats in selenium

Tags: format, price

I am writing scripts to capture price of products for an  e-commerce site. I dont know how to convert price from

12
$10.   to $10.12 format in selenium. for example if we search any product in amazon site, it displays product price in the above format. Please help me to write code to change this to normal format like $10.12.

example : https://www.amazon.com/s?k=cleanser&crid=3B21XGR0OATTU&sprefix=%2Caps%2C698&ref=nb_sb_ss_recent_1_0_recent

Thanks.